# plot linear regressions lines without interaction in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression

This code plots regression lines with interactions in ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg, group = cyl)) + geom_point() + stat_smooth(method = "lm")
```

[image]

Can lines without interactions be plotted with `stat_smooth`?

Comment: Slope for each of three regression lines should be same

Comment: So take `, group = cyl` out?

Comment: Three regression lines (one for each group of cyl) that each have the same slope but different intercept

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Workaround would be to make model outside the `ggplot()`. Then make predicition for this model and add result to the original data frame. This will add columns `fit`, `lwr` and `upr`.

```
mod<-lm(mpg~factor(cyl)+hp,data=mtcars)
mtcars<-cbind(mtcars,predict(mod,interval="confidence"))
```

Now you can use `geom_line()` with `fit` values as `y` to add three regression lines and `geom_ribbon()` with `lwr` and `upr` to add confidence interval.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg, group = cyl)) + geom_point() +
      geom_line(aes(y=fit))+geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lwr,ymax=upr),alpha=0.4)
```

[image]