# R: ggplot - YX relationship with 2 groups - how to get only one (whole sample) slope?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot the relationship between X (score) and Y (age) for two groups. I am using:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=score, y=age, color=group, shape=group)) + 
    geom_point(size=3) + geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, fullrange=TRUE) + 
    labs(....) +
    theme_minimal(base_size = 15)
```

[image]

I would like each group to have a different colour and shape on the plot. However, I am not interested in the slope for each group but the slope for the whole sample.

Could you please let me know how I can get that?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you want parallel lines a la [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23722905/plot-linear-regressions-lines-without-interaction-in-ggplot2) or a single line?  If the latter, move `color` and `shape` to within `geom_point` instead of in the global `aes`.

Comment: just add `stat_smooth(..., group = NULL)`