# plotting a simplified lm (factors and numerical values as explanatory variables) using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm

I am using lms to analyse data and simplify models using backwards selection. Now it is really easy to plot that outcome in `R` base-package via `predict()`, but I struggle to do so in `ggplot2`.

To be more specific about my model, I am having a metric dependent variable and a metric variable, a factor (22 levels) as explanatory variables as well as the interactions thereof. During the simplification process I find, that the interaction is non-significant, so can be deleted from the minimum adequate model. For simplicity I am demonstrating my issue using the `mtcar` dataset and transforming `cyl` as a factor:

```
mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)
   model <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + wt, data = mtcars)
   summary(model)
```

so my simplified model lacks the interaction. I now want to plot the data in `ggplot2`:

```
cyl <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, col = cyl, fill = cyl, group = cyl))                        
   cyl + geom_point(size = 3, alpha = 0.3) + stat_smooth(method = "lm", se = F)
```

If I am plotting the data using `stat_smooth`, I get separate regression lines for each factor levels with differences in intercept and slope, which is not what the simplified model suggests. But how do I implement this in `gglot2`? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23722905/plot-linear-regressions-lines-without-interaction-in-ggplot2

Comment: Thanks, but that dosn't work for my dataset. cbind isn't working as the columns differ in length..

Comment: I'd guess that's due to missing data: a few options, heres two:  in the original `lm` model use `lm(... na.action = na.exclude)`, then predictions should have `NA` included; or omit the missing variables prior to fitting the model i.e. `newdata=na.omit(data)`, then fit and predict on `newdata`

Comment: Can you post your data using `dput()`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! It worked better for me to exclude the data from the original dataset since I had problems with including the regression lines via `geom_line`  as the lines were discontinuous for the factor levels.