# Dose-response plot with two separate linear regression lines

Tags: r, plot, linear-regression

I'm doing a dose-response plot where the dietary intake (x-axis) divides in two intervention groups (high protein vs. low protein) and y-axis shows the change in a bone outcome.

["x" is defined from a variable in my dataset called "Protein", where the factor "1" is high protein and "2" is low protein](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfxNu.png)

I want to do a linear regression line showing the association between intake and change in bone outcome, however, since the assumption of normal distribution is not true, I would like to do two separate lines — one for each group (high vs. low) — showing the association.

I have used the following code:

```
abline(lm(y ~ x:factor(Protein) + factor(Protein) -1, data = CC_compliance.long), col = "blue")
```

However, the plot only shows one line, which doesn't make any sense:

[image: Dose-response plot with only one linear regression line]

I'm thinking that it may have something to do with the code not being able to differentiate between Protein=1 and Protein=2. Can i define this in another way?

Dataset:

```
structure(list(Protein = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2), Change_bone = c(72.1, 132.2, 57.8, 55.6, 30.4, 49.1, 46.8, 24.6, 44.8, 96.4), Protein_intake = c(20.9, 11.2, 7.9, 17.5, 10, 1.5, 9.3, 20, 22.5, 10.4)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please add a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/11570343). This is what you [want?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23725971/11570343).

Comment: I added a snippet of my dataset from Excel as an image to the post. This is my first Stackoverflow post, so I'm not sure what else to add or what you need.

Comment: Instead of showing a screenshot of your data, please use `dput()` or one of the approaches mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to put your data in your question in a more convenient form ...

Comment: I added a structure to my post now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ggplot` like here:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = df, aes(x = Protein_intake, y = Change_bone)) +
  geom_smooth(data = df[df$Protein == 1, ], 
              aes(x = Protein_intake, y = Change_bone, color = "1"),
              method = "lm",
              se = FALSE) +
  geom_smooth(data = df[df$Protein == 2, ],
              aes(x = Protein_intake, y = Change_bone, color = "2"),
              method = "lm", 
              se = FALSE) +
  scale_colour_manual(name="legend", values=c("blue", "red"))
```

Or with `graphics` you may use:

```
plot(df$Protein_intake, df$Change_bone) +
abline(reg = lm(Change_bone ~ Protein_intake , data = df[df$Protein == 1,]), col = "blue") +
abline(lm(Change_bone ~ Protein_intake , data = df[df$Protein == 2,]), col = "red")
```

Comment: I tried the ggplot with my own dataset and got the error:
"Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (85): x and y"

Then i tried the graphics and got the error:
"Error: need finite 'ylim' values"